# concatenate all values in NSMutableDictionary cast to int, NSInteger and NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, casting, concatenation, nsmutabledictionary

so I have a couple NSMutableDictionarys and each key/valeu pair for a specific dictionary hold either a string or integer value. I would like to know if there is a way to iterate through the dictionary and concatenate the values. In PHP I could do something like this using an array

```
// either the dictionary holds all integers or all string values
$integer_array = array( 'a' => 2, 'b' => 9, 'c' => 2, 'd' => 0, 'e' => 1 );

foreach( $integer_array as $key => $value ) {
    $concatenated_value .= $value;
}

// cast to int
$concatenated_value = ( int ) $concatenated_value;

// prints: 29201
echo $concatenated_value;
```

I could also use the [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) as well

```
$concatenated_value = ( int )(implode("", $integer_array));

// prints: 29201
echo $concatenated_value;
```

is there something like this for iOS Objective-C?

Comment: `NSDictionary` in Objective C are not sorted, so concatenations will be random, unless you sort keys and then concatenate values in a loop.

Comment: yes, sort within the loop is what I was thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a predefined function for it.  To me, this doesn't seem like a very common thing to do (is it common in PHP?).  I suppose the code would look like this in theory:

```
int finalVal = 0;
for (NSString *key in keyArray)
{
    //If it is variable between NSString and NSNumber as you say, you will
    //need to do type checking here.
    NSNumber *numVal = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    int num = [numVal intValue];

    //----Don't need this part if all values are single digits
    while(num > 10)
    {
        finalVal += num;
        finalVal *= 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    finalVal += num;
    finalVal *= 10;
}
finalVal /= 10;
```

However, this is very unlikely to produce the results you want since dictionaries are not ordered.  I think you need a different data structure or an array holding the keys in the order you inserted them (but at that point you might as well just use an array).

**EDIT** Since you are using an ordered array of keys, I edited the answer above.

Comment: Yes I have another NSArray with the key order for the iteration and would pull the value of the dictionary by key and concatenate it

Comment: Well, that will only take a small change in the code.  I will edit

Comment: why finalVal *= 10; and finalVal /= 10; could you go a little more into detail as to what this is doing? otherwise great example! And yes this is very common in PHP

Comment: This loop will multiply by 10 one too many times, so to balance that I divide by 10 once at the end.  Why multiply?  It's just math!  If I use the digits 1, 2, 3, and 4 to make a number it will be 1 * 1000 + 2  * 100 + 3 * 10 + 4.  So first 0 + 1 = 1, 1 * 10 = 10, 10 + 2 = 12, 12 * 10 = 120, 120 + 3 = 123, 123 * 10 = 1230, 1230 + 4 = 1234, 1234 * 10 = 12340 (oops, too far, so cancel the last one), 12340 / 10 = 1234;

Comment: P.S. What do you consider to be the most practical application of this function?

Comment: :) Will post back once I release my app, and thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it (it's quite a bit longer, due to the fact that dictionaries in cocoa are not ordered).

```
NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"a",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"b",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:34], @"c",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:56], @"d",nil];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [[d allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
NSMutableString *res = [NSMutableString string];
[sortedKeys enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [res appendFormat:@"%d", [[d objectForKey:obj] intValue]];
}];
NSLog(@"%@", res);
```

This prints `123456`

Comment: Could you show how to do this with the dictionary key/values reversed? so 'a' is the key and the value would be '1'

Comment: @PhillPafford That is what the code snippet is already showing: numbers are values, strings are keys (that is how the `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` works).

Comment: I think I've been looking at the screen too long, I knew this LOL thanks!